# What are BB-8's class of droids designed for?

Tags: star-wars, droids, the-force-awakens

It's well-known that C-3PO is a protocol droid.

R2-D2 is an astromech.

## What is BB-8 and what does that function entail?

This is likely to be answerable now based on marketing material or toy releases,  but please note per meta discussion, it is against policy to use information from *The Force Awakens* before its official release.  And the answer should be spoiler tagged if it contains any plot elements or other spoilerish information.

Comment: BB-8 is designed for selling plastic toys.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## BB-8 is an astromech droid.

[image]

According to the ***official Star Wars Databank entry***,

> BB-8 is the spherical, loyal **Astromech Droid** of the Resistance pilot Poe Dameron.

([Source](http://www.starwars.com/databank/bb-8))

According to another entry in the Databank:

> Astromech droids are a series of versatile utility robots **generally used for the maintenance and repair of starships and related technology**. These small droids are often equipped with a variety of tool-tipped appendages that are stowed in recessed compartments. The R2 unit is a popular example of an astromech droid.

([Source](http://www.starwars.com/databank/astromech-droid))

Here is a t-shirt with the answer:

[image]

Finally, here is a licensed toy with BB-8 sitting in the traditional astromech position in a *Force Awakens*-era X Wing:

[image]

Before anyone asks, yes, the BB-8 and the X Wing come as a set:

[image]

And here's a screen grab from a trailer (thanks **@Clockwork-Muse**):

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't have guessed that.   Interesting!

Comment: Can we get a picture of BB-8 astromeching?  Does it sound the same as R2-D2?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Done!

Comment: I wonder how it sticks to the surface of ships like R2-D2 did in TPM.

Comment: For that matter, one of the trailers [has a shot of him in an x-wing](http://braindamaged.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/star-wars-force-awakens-bb-8-x-wing-600x251.jpg).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse : Thanks -- I've added this!

Comment: @Jamil how did R2 units stick to the hull for that matter?

Comment: @Xantec I assumed they had magnetic treads or something similar, but I don't see how that would translate to a spherical body.

Comment: @Jamil just give the exterior of BB-8's body a magnetic charge.

Comment: @Xantec Which it likely has anyway, to keep the head attached.

Comment: Also, BB-8 has cables he can shoot from his body to attach himself to things.  I'm more curious of how they're going to make a toy droid like my R2 unit which can move around and can "see" objects and pick up heat signatures.  Also he plays games and the Leia message.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Having now seen the film, I can say with confidence that we don't really see BB-8 astromeching (although there is no question that he is an astromech droid).  At best, he sits in the back of Dameron's x wing.  There are many, many shots of him rolling around though and, as Nate says, there's a sequence in which he uses cables from his body to attach himself to walls.

Comment: @praxis  that IS astromeching.....part of it at least the sitting in the back of an x wing and helping the pilot operating the machine. Aside from that only the calculate hyperspace coordinates is left which we havent seen so far.

Comment: In TLJ BB-8 also does some decent astromeching for Poe's X-wing