# What tools have Astromech droids demonstrated in canon?

Tags: star-wars, droids

As linked in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110377/3823), the official *Star Wars* Databank describes:

> Astromech droids are a series of versatile utility robots generally used for the maintenance and repair of starships and related technology. These small droids are often equipped with a variety of tool-tipped appendages that are stowed in recessed compartments. The R2 unit is a popular example of an astromech droid.

([Source](http://www.starwars.com/databank/astromech-droid))

## What are the tools that have been demonstrated in canon?

Comment: Does canon include Clone Wars (with that astromech mini-arc) and Rebels and "Chopper"?

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you think I should address before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Star Wars Blueprints: The Ultimate Collection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756638690) book lists the following components available to the R2 Unit

- Drink Serving Unit (presumably this is not a standard feature but one added by Jabba's men)
- Fine Manipulator Arm
- Spacecraft Linkage and Control Arms
- Universal Computer Interface Arm
- Utility Saw
- Multi-function Utility and Interface Arm
- Lubricant Reservoir (*which can be emptied at will*)
- Extendable Auxiliary Visual Imaging System
- Lifeform Scanner
- Kerner Optical Holographic Projector
- Signal Amplifier
- Fire Extinguisher
- Inflight Maintenance Grasper Arm
- Electro-Magnet Power Charge Arm
- Mechanical Grasper Arm

[image]

Comment: Does this agree with what is demonstrated in the film (including prequels) ?

Comment: Also, your link is no good.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - It certainly seems to agree with the films

Comment: Was this 'extendable neck' demonstrated?

Comment: And what about other droids?   (Rx class and BB-x class?)

Comment: Where is the holoprojector?

Comment: @Mark:   It's there, #33.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I'm struggling to find any instance where the "extendo-neck" comes into play. By the same token, I can't find anything that disagrees with it.

Comment: I didn't see the little thrusters for flying that R2 uses in the prequels.  Maybe I missed it.

Comment: @MarkRogers - #49 - "Booster Turbines"

Comment: @Richard:    Yeah, I don't remember seeing that either.   But the 'specifically for Naboo' suggests it's there for a reason.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Looking at the scene where Anakin steals a Naboobian fighter, I can kinda see why they needed to explain how R2 fits into the socket. There's not enough space for his feet. That being said, what an unnecessary attention to detail :-)

Comment: @Richard:   screencap?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - "*Doug Chiang has acknowledged that an R2 unit cannot physically exist inside the frame of the spacecraft as it is depicted in Episode I and later in Episode II. His original concept artwork did allow for the legs of an R2 unit to fit within the tube-shaped socket, but George Lucas directed him to make the socket tube diameter the same, or nearly the same, as the diameter of the droid's head, which does not allow enough room for the legs of the droid."*

Comment: @ThePopMachine - "*A compromise was reached in the Star Wars: Episode I Incredible Cross-Sections book which [shows Artoo Detoo collapsing his legs and telescoping his head above his body](https://ivyarchenland.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/dkpublishing-starwars-incrediblecross-sections-episodei-thephantommenace-013.jpg) until it was above the viewing threshold."*

Comment: @Richard:    Now **that** is interesting!   Why not add to the answer?   Why?   Because it proves that it actually is demonstrated in I and II.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Because it's the answer to a question not asked

Comment: @Richard:  OK, only because the extendable neck is not a 'tool'.   Look for a new question soon.

Answer (score 4):

R2-D2 has shown the use of a data prong, a power connection, an oil slick, a grasping claw, a periscope, holo recorder/projector, jets, grappling hook, saws, plasma cutters/soldering iron like tool, and a scanner dish.